# How do I declare variables when I'm prompting the user to enter them?

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm trying to learn call functions and I've come across a problem where I'm being told I need I need to declare `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, but the point of the program is to prompt the user for these numbers and then sum them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int f(int a, int b, int c, int d); 
int g(int b, int c, int d);
int h(int c, int d);
int i(int d);

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        int result;
        result = f(a,b,c,d);
        printf("Value of a?");
        scanf("%d",a);
        printf("Value of b?");
        scanf("%d",b);
        printf("Value of c?");
        scanf("%d",c);
        printf("Value of d?");
        scanf("%d",d);
        printf("Your result is %d",result);
        return 0;
}

int
f(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return a + g(b,c,d);
}

int
g(int b, int c, int d)
{
        return b + h(c,d);
}

int
h(int c, int d)
{
        return c + i(d);
}

int
i(int d)
{
        return d + d;
}
```

The specific warning is

```
    call.c:16:13: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      result = f(a,b,c,d);
```

and it repeats for b, c, and d.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? I put the function signatures at the top where `int a`, `int b`, `int c`, and `int d` are already defined so I'm confused as to what I've done incorrectly.

Edit: Question has been solved! The code should look like

```
        int result;
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        printf("Value of a?");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("Value of b?");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        printf("Value of c?");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        printf("Value of d?");
        scanf("%d",&d);
        result = f(a,b,c,d);
        printf("Your result is %d",result);
        return 0;
```

Comment: Declare them right after `int result`;

Comment: FYI, please use more descriptive variable/function names.

Comment: The parameters to the function f are unrelated to the a, b, c, d in main. You could have called them w, x, y, z or whatever. They need to be declared in main.

Comment: After int result I enter
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

and it gives me even more warnings, such as 
     call.c:24:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type      ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
      scanf("%d",b);
and tells me that a, b, c, and d are uninitialized.
Apparently the formatting in comments is something I cannot use well.

Comment: scanf expects a pointer: scanf("%d", &a);

Comment: Thank you Johnny! We haven't officially learned about scanf yet, so I did not know that. That solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Your updated solution is not correct. You are calling f() with uninitialized variables. The call to f() should be right before the last printf()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare those variables in main, try changing your code to

`int result, a, b, c, d;`

Also `scanf` expects pointers in it's variadic portion of arguments, 
so you're going to need to use the `&` reference operator to take the address of `a`

Example: `scanf("%d", &a);`
And do this for all of your `scanf` calls.